# Integrate $\int\frac{x}{(x^4-1)\cdot\sqrt{x^2+1}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $\int\frac{x}{(x^4-1)\cdot\sqrt{x^2+1}} \, dx$

I tried substituting $x=\tan(t)$ in order to get away with square root. ($\:dx=\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}dt\:$)

$\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{\cos(t)}\:\:$ ***and*** $\:\:x^4-1=\frac{\sin^4(t)-\cos^4(t)}{\cos^4(t)}$

Now after putting both into main Integral and by simplifying I have :
$$
\int\frac{\sin(t)\cdot\cos^2(t)}{\sin^4(t)-\cos^4(t)} \, dt=\text{?}
$$
Now need a bit help if possible.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{x^2+1}=y, dy=\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

$$\implies x^2=y^2-1$$

$$\int\dfrac{dy}{(y^2-1)^2-1}=\int\dfrac{dy}{y^2(y^2-2)}$$

Now use,
$$\dfrac2{y^2(y^2-2)}=\dfrac{y^2-(y^2-2)}{y^2(y^2-2)}=\dfrac1{y^2-2}-\dfrac1{y^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

A hint: $\sin^2(t)+\cos^2 (t)=1$ but
$$
\begin{split}
\sin^4(t)-\cos^4 (t) & =\big(\sin^2(t)-\cos^2 (t)\big)\big(\sin^2(t)+\cos^2 (t)\big)\\
&= \sin^2(t)-\cos^2 (t)
\end{split}
$$
Therefore your integral is
$$
\begin{split}
\int\frac{\sin(t)\cdot\cos^2(t)}{\sin^4(t)-\cos^4(t)}dt=\int\frac{\sin(t)}{\tan^2(t)-1}dt
\end{split}
$$

Comment: @John simply divide numerator and denominator by $\cos(t)$

Comment: @John Or just use partial fractions.

Answer (score 4):

Note

\begin{align}
\int\frac{\sin t\cos^2t}{\sin^4t-\cos^4t} \, dt
= &\int\frac{\sin t\cos^2t}{(1-\cos^2t)^2-\cos^4t} \, dt
=\int\frac{\sin t\cos^2t}{1-2\cos^2t} \, dt\\
 = & \frac12 \int\left( 1- \frac{1}{1-2\cos^2t} \right) \, d(\cos t)\\
=&\frac12\cos t -\frac1{4\sqrt2}\ln \frac{1+\sqrt2\cos t}{1-\sqrt2\cos t}
\end{align}

Comment: can't get that $d(cos(t))$ but however i have the same final part as yours and than by replacing $t=arctan(x)$, i came to the final result (p.s ur elaboration is much more shorter would like to understand) :)

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
& \frac 1 2 \int\frac 1 {(x^4-1)\sqrt{x^2+1}} (2x \, dx) \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac 1 2 \int \frac{du}{(u^2-1)\sqrt{u+1}} \\ {} \\
& v = \sqrt{u+1} \\
& v^2 -1 = u \\
& 2v\,dv = du
\end{align}
$$
After that you're integrating a rational function and you may need partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int \frac x{\left(x^4 - 1\right) \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \, dx \\
&= - \int \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-y}{1+y}}}{\left(\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2} - 1\right) \sqrt{\frac{1-y}{1+y} + 1}} \, \sqrt{\frac{1+y}{1-y}} \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2} \tag1 \\
&= \frac1{4\sqrt2} \int \frac{\sqrt{1+y}}y \, dy \\
&= \frac1{4\sqrt2} \int \frac{z}{z^2-1} \, 2z\,dz \tag2 \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \int \left(1+\frac1{z^2-1}\right) \,dz \\
&= \frac{z-\tanh^{-1}z}{2\sqrt2} + C \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{y+1} - \tanh^{-1}\sqrt{y+1}}{2\sqrt2} + C \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\frac2{1+x^2}} - \tanh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac2{1+x^2}}}{2\sqrt2} + C
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $x=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}}$
- $(2)$ : substitute $z=\sqrt{y+1}$